# чтение файла, преобразование строки в список

Tags: python-3.x

имею файл с списками в формате

```html
['62', '99', '10', '24', '16', '22', '20', '29', '16', '24']
['63', '39', '10', '5', '18', '10', '17', '11', '18', '13']
['64', '87', '23', '15', '10', '24', '12', '30', '19', '18']
['133', '26', '36', '4', '29', '2', '34', '11', '34', '9']
['53', '61', '8', '18', '11', '12', '12', '10', '22', '21']
```

подскажите как мне прочитать файл, чтобы на выходе Я имел не строки, а список

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python-у приходится парсить файлы с кодом и некоторые из инструментов доступны пользователю.

```
from ast import literal_eval as make_list

with open('file.dat', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        cur_lst = make_list(line)
        print(cur_lst)
```

Comment: подскажите, почему мне выдает такую ошибку?

cur_lst = make_list(line)
  File "C:\Users\ex3m777\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ast.py", line 46, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "C:\Users\ex3m777\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1

Comment: @ex3m777 Извините. Не знаю. Могу только предположить, что функции не понравилась строка. Возможно кодировка. Возможно какие-то лидирующие или завершающие, отображаемые или неотображаемые символы. Попробуйте перед преобразованием, каждую линию вывести на печать и поискать, на чем функция спотыкается.